# Why does passing a non-static member function cause compilation errors?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to invoke the below constructor, passing it a static member function I don't get any errors but when I pass it a non-static member function I get a compilations error:

**Constructor**

```
template <class callable, class... arguments>
Timer(int after, duration_type duration, bool async, callable&& f, arguments&&... args)
{

    std::function<typename std::result_of<callable(arguments...)>::type()> 
            task(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));

}
```

**Invokation**

```
Timer timer(252222, duration_type::milliseconds, true, &MotionAnalyser::ObjectGarbageCollector); // Does not work because it does not point to object too.

Timer timer(252222, duration_type::milliseconds, true, std::bind(this, &MotionAnalyser::ObjectGarbageCollector)); //Should work, but does not?!?!
```

**Error**

```
Error   C2039   'type': is not a member of 'std::result_of<callable (void)>'
```

So far I have:

- Looked into how `std:function` is used, which turned out to be in
  conjunction with a callable type, the invoking object should be a
  callable type since I over-rode the `()` operator (based on my
  understanding of callable types).
- I have looked into passing non-static member functions to a function
  hence my attempt at using `std::bind`
- Googled around for useful info on the compilation error.

Comment: I don't really understand what ::type() here is, would be nice if you can shed some light on that too.

Comment: It would be quite pleasing if you would submit a complete example of your work along with some discussion regarding research you have done to answer your question...

Comment: When calling non static member function you must pass the object argument: `std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), *this,std::forward<arguments>(args)...)`

Comment: Why are you calling `bind` when you construct the object when the constructor calls `bind` itself?

Comment: I think you have your bind call backwards, you pass the callable object first and then the arguments to the binder call afterwards. `std::bind(&MotionAnalyser::ObjectGarbageCollector, this)`

Comment: @SirGuy I think you're right, compilation errors are gone :) Please submit as an answer for me to mark.

Comment: @Oliv I have to because this is the only way I can pass that function call as argument, you are right though it does do it again in the function definition.

Comment: Seems that ::type is only valid from C++14 version and upper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your call to `bind` backwards, it takes the callable object first (in this case the pointer to member function) and then the parameters afterwards.

```
std::bind(&MotionAnalyser::ObjectGarbageCollector, this)
```

However, looking at the constructor for `Timer` you should be able to pass those arguments along, since they get bound anyway:

```
Timer timer(252222, duration_type::milliseconds, true,
            &MotionAnalyser::ObjectGarbageCollector, this);
```